# Проблема с использованием цикла for

Tags: java, циклы

Всем привет! Я только новичок и пытаюсь разобраться с циклом **for** в Java.

Есть задача:

> A bus tour of Europe has been very successful. Due to an increase in
>   the number of people that want to go on a tour, the tour company
>   decided to increase the height of the bus. The new height of the bus
>   is exactly N centimeters.
>
> But the tour’s route runs under a lot of bridges, and there is a
>   chance that the bus will crash into one of these bridges. Can you find
>   out if this will happen?
>
> The first line of the input contains the height of the bus and number
>   of bridges under which the bus passes. The second line contains
>   heights of these bridges.
>
> You should output "Will not crash" if everything will be all right;
>   otherwise, output "Will crash on bridge i" (where i is a number of a
>   bridge) into which the bus will crash. If the height of a bridge
>   equals the height of the bus, the bus will crash.
>
> **Sample Input 1:**
>
> 234 8
>
> 465 453 981 463 1235 871 475 981
>
> **Sample Output 1:**
>
> Will not crash
>
> **Sample Input 2:**
>
> 211 5
>
> 871 205 123 871 1681
>
> **Sample Output 2:**
>
> Will crash on bridge 2

**Мой код:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int heightOfTheBus = scanner.nextInt();
        int numberOfTheBridge = scanner.nextInt();
        int heightOfTheBridge;
        int i;

        for (i = 1; i <= numberOfTheBridge; i++) {
            heightOfTheBridge = scanner.nextInt();
            if (heightOfTheBus < heightOfTheBridge) {
                System.out.println("Will not crash");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Will crash on bridge " + i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что когда я ввожу значение высоты моста, компилятор сразу выводит сообщение попадёт ли автобус в автокатастрофу.
Как сделать, чтобы сообщение об этом выводилось только тогда, как все значения высот уже введены?

Мой output:

[image: Мой output]

Comment: Убрать вывод "всё орлайт" за пределы цикла. В случае краша - сразу завершать main.

Comment: @Akina Пробовал так, пишет: variable 'heightOfTheBridge' might not have been initialized.

Comment: Вы правда думаете, что МЫ будем отлаживать ВАШУ программу?

Comment: @Akina Если бы знал, то не стал бы спрашивать...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрите, вы написали

> ```
> for (i = 1; i <= numberOfTheBridge; i++) {
>     heightOfTheBridge = scanner.nextInt();
>     if (heightOfTheBus < heightOfTheBridge) {
>         System.out.println("Will not crash");
>     } else {
>         System.out.println("Will crash on bridge " + i);
>     }
> }
> ```

А ошибка ваша вот в чем: циклы предназначены для повторяющихся действий, а вы поместили в цикл то действие, которое повторяться не должно. Вам нужно сначала обойти мосты, а потом один раз вывести ответ, а не для каждого моста ответ. Вынесите вывод из цикла наружу.

И еще один момент: судя по вашему неравенству, если высота моста больше высоты автобуса, то он в него врежется, а если меньше, то пролезет. Поменяйте знак.

У вас должно быть что-то типа

```
boolean crash = false;
for (i = 0; i < numberOfTheBridge; i++) {
    heightOfTheBridge = scanner.nextInt();
    if (heightOfTheBus > heightOfTheBridge) {
        crash = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (crash) ... else ... // вывод ответа
```

Цикл вида `for (i = 0, i < n` более распространен и привычен глазу программиста, так как он подойдет и для массивов, где индексы начинаются с нуля, и еще много для чего, но это уже совсем другая история.

Comment: Всё супер! Только должно быть i = 1 и heightOfTheBus >= heightOfTheBridge, судя по условию.

Comment: Тогда кстати может и есть смысл в данном примере считать с единицы. Ну я думаю суть понятна